# How to compare 2 Json object files using key attributes using kotlin in a reusable way?

Tags: json, kotlin

I'm trying to compare 2 JSONs files for equality(order doesn't matter).

I have tried using Comparable but looking for an efficient way which will compare each key attribute of 1 JSON object file to another one in a loop every time files are generated and return true or false based on the comparison.

Comment: I'd say to use a streaming api, or object binding api if you are not concerned about  memory.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe use `Gson`.

Create a data class for your JSON, for example, `CarDetails`.

Deserialize your two strings to objects and compare them.

```
Gson g = new Gson(); 
CarDetails cd1 = g.fromJson(carDetailsAsString1, CarDetails::class.java)
CarDetails cd2 = g.fromJson(carDetailsAsString2, CarDetails::class.java)
return cd1 == cd2
```

Comment: @lce how about in Kotlin. Is there any specific api or any alternative approach which is more reusable and generic.

Comment: I think you can load this JSONs to two separate `List<String>` and then search one element of the list in the second list, if you find a match then remove this item from both lists. If not, JSONs are not equal.

Comment: and how about implementing Comparable rather deserialize json??. Both json objects are of different type basically.

Comment: basically i have 10 json files and i want to compare them with other json files for equality and write a class/method in Kotlin. i checked docs but couldn't figure out. Appreciate any ideas.

Comment: I've already given you 2 possible solutions. Comparable can't be applied here because you have different types of JSONs.

Comment: great. i will try that out. thanks for the response